# Pointer received as parameter

Tags: c, pointers

Given the following piece of code :

```
f1() 
{
 int *x;
 f2(&x);
}

f2(int **x)
{
  // Before any processing, make sure that the reference to x is NULL
  if (x != NULL)
  {
    *x = NULL;
  }
}
```

I am not sure if this piece of code really makes sense. What I wanted to do was to be sure that the pointer to x, the one declared in f1 and received as parameter by f2, is NULL(because in f1 where it was declared it wasn't initialized to NULL).

Comment: That looks fine and the null-pointer check is a good precaution.

Comment: that doesn't protect against uninitialized pointer like in f1 though.

Comment: As noted by @Jean-FrançoisFabre It doesn't check against uninitialized `x` though, like if called as `int **x; f2(x);`. But then it's impossible to check for uninitialized variables anyway so no need to trying to figure it out. All you can do is document the `f2` function well, specifying exactly what it needs, perhaps with an example, and if someone uses it wrongly then point to the documentation.

Comment: sometimes it's good to just let the program crash. Writing to NULL crashes at once, and a debugger allows to find exactly where it crashed. On the other hand, if someone passes a null pointer, the code doesn't do anything, and it may crash later anyway.

Comment: All looks fine.

Comment: Note that your functions aren't defined properly as you don't specify the type of the return value.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre why do you say that it may crash later? I don't understand. Can you please give me an example?
In f2, before any usage of *x, I check if x != NULL

Comment: well, if you pass a null pointer, then you avoid the crash, but this null pointer remains in your execution data context, so at some point you'll access it later and it will crash…

Comment: @SamStewart *This* code isn't going to do any crashing unless someone passes a bogus pointer address (i.e some `int**` itself that isn't proper. Not much you can do about that (Sooner or later, its *not* turtles all the way down). But, I don't see any issue with this code as presented (save for the fantasy C code in general). Your stated goal in your last paragraph matches up with what you seem to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
f1() { int *x;  f2(&x);  }

f2 (int **x) {
  // Before any processing, make sure that the reference to x is NULL
  if (x != NULL)  *x = NULL;
}
```

In f1() there is clearly an error (uninitialized variable), and you want to test that in f2(). In reality, f1() could be fine if the variable x is intended as an `out` parameter of f2(), but from this example and your explanation does not seem to be so.

f2() can check if x is NULL, but it can't check other kind of errors like errating pointer. Here, and often in C programs in general, NULL *is* a valid value - sometimes (often) that value is used to say "this variable has not yet a value", or "I am not interested in this parameter".

f2() can not, in any way, check for the validity of its parameter. It would be possible, up to 99% perhaps, with other mechanisms: for example, if a pointer is not NULL, dereference it and check for a special marker, or pass it to some other function which can do the check. This is anyway tricky, because a wild pointer can trigger anyway an exception. And, even if dereferencing the pointer does not trigger an exception, and by pure coincidence there is the correct marker where it should be, that is not a guarantee of the correctness of the pointer!

But, as noted in comments above, the problem is wider. If the called function discovers that a parameter is invalid, what to do then? Ignoring it just to avoid a segmentation fault is a starting point, but not enough safe because the caller of the function probably expects the called function to do something useful; if that something useful is not done, the caller must be notified, otherwise it goes ahead with wrong assumptions. There are situations where this lack of checking is acceptable, but they are not elegant anyway.

I've read somewhere that it is not always correct, for a function, to check for the validity of incoming parameters: software written that way tends to be longer, slower, and maybe flawed because every line of added code may introduce errors. A well written function should assume that the caller is well-behaved. Probably, in certain dangerous cases, some check is still advisable.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, there is lots to comment about this piece of code, but I assume you took the nuts and bolts of the original code to make your point, so I will not get into those details...

Coming to your code

```
f1() 
{
 int *x;
 f2(&x); /* you are passing address of the variable x which is a pointer to an int */
}

f2(int **x)
{
  // Before any processing, make sure that the reference to x is NULL
  if (x != NULL)
  {
    *x = NULL;
  }
  /* at this point, the memory location pointed by the passed argument x, 
   * which happen to be another pointer to an int, is NULL. The local
   * variable x of f2() is not NULL, only the memory location it is point 
   * to contains the NULL value.
   */
}
```